# Calculate correlation for new data points

Tags: correlation

I understand we can calculate the correlation using `Pearson Product-Moment Correlation` from two list of data points. But if I have a new pair of data points, what math formula can I use to update the correlation value without re-calculate the whole things? Something like existing_cor_value + [formula]?

Comment: An answer can be found here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance    First use the online algorithms for variance and covariance, then finally recalculate $r$ from its definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the information from the original calculation, you can add the new data pair to these sums and recalculate.

[image]

Source: http://davidmlane.com/hyperstat/A51911.html

Another way to approach this would be to take the z scores of your new data pair (which would require knowing the mean and standard deviation of x and y). This would allow you to use this formula:

[image]

That will be a bit off, since you likely wouldn't be updating the means and standard deviations.